# Why are quarks fundamental particles?

Tags: standard-model, quarks, elementary-particles

A neutron decays into a proton by changing one of its down quark into an up quark and releasing energy, positron and neutrino particle.

So, a down quark can decay into an up quark.

**If a quark decays, why is it considered a fundamental particle?**

Comment: What do you mean it can "break" into an up quark?

Comment: I've flagged this for closing because it's unclear what you're asking and seems to show absolutely no prior research.

Comment: The term "break" is generally used when something separates from a collection of items, into those items by themselves.  You might say, "a hydrogen molecule $H_2$ can *break* into its constituent hydrogen atoms, $H$ and $H$".  But you don't say that something "breaks" when it changes into another thing.

Comment: It's pretty clear that OP is questioning about quark *decays*.

Answer (score 3):

Quarks decay by the [weak interaction :](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/particles/qrkdec.html)

t -> b -> c -> s -> u <-> d

[image: quark decays]

> - The W bosons which are indicated as W* are virtual bosons, existing only within the time frame allowed by the uncertainty principle. The positive W* decays to a positron and an electron neutrino, and the negative W* to an electron and antineutrino as can be seen in the example reactions above.

So quark number , 1/3 of baryon number is conserved. Quarks in decaying  weakly change the quantum numbers characterizing them, except the baryon number.

They are considered elementary point particles of the [standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) . It is a hypothesis, and since the standard model calculations fit innumerable data very well,   it is accepted that they are elementary particles together with a set of other particles, leptons and gauge bosons and the Higgs.

Comment: But I still do not get why are quarks, except up quark, elementary if they can decay into smaller particles of less energy.

Comment: They are called elementary because they are used as a basis for the standard model SU(3)xSU(2)xU(1). The quarks are in the strong SU(3) group . They are point particles and they acquire their mass through the Higgs mechanism. At high energies , before the Higgs mechanism is activated, they are all massless, and they still will change through weak interactions (SU(2)) to each other, still a quark remaining. That is the standard physics view at present.